# redux-form: need help in understanding syntax

Tags: reactjs, jsx, redux-form

I am going through the video of `redux-form`. I found the following code:

```
const renderInput = ({ input, meta, label}) =>
      <div>
        <label>{label}</label>
        <input {...input} />
        {meta.error &&
          <span>
            {meta.error}
          </span>}
      </div>
```

I did not understand the below segment:

```
    {meta.error &&
      <span>
        {meta.error}
      </span>}
```

Can we use jsx inside `{}` ? Here `<span>` is used inside {}. I thought only javascript variables or expressions are used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this syntax is allowed.
Let me quote some parts of the docs...

> ## Embedding Expressions in JSX
>
> You can embed any JavaScript expression in JSX by wrapping it in curly braces.

[Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

> ## JSX is an expression too
>
> After compilation, JSX expressions become regular JavaScript objects.

[Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-is-an-expression-too)

These two sentences complete each other in regards to what is allowed within JSX.

Because its output is simply JS, you can recursively embed JS blocks in JSX elements with other JSX elements in them and so on.
It's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @gustavohenke's answer, the code segment

```
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <input {...input} />
    {meta.error &&
      <span>
        {meta.error}
      </span>}
  </div>
```

is used to conditionally render a `<span>` element containing the contents (possibly error message) of `meta.error`, if `meta.error` has some value. The code uses [short circuit evaluation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-short-circuit-evaluation-ff22b2f5608c) to do the same. Hope you get it now!

Comment: Thank you for the short circuit evaluation thing. I was looking for both the answers (short circuit evaluation and JSX {}).  Both of the answers helped me a lot